# is it possible to delete the image file after download using flask or python

Tags: python, url, flask, beautifulsoup, request

I am currently working on a small web interface which allows download files.i can download  the image link from the url by connecting to the ip camera . after downloading it should delete.

```
# specify the URL of the archive here 
archive_url = "http://192.168.42.1/SD/AMBA/191116000/"

def get_img_links(): 

    # create response object 
    r = requests.get(archive_url) 

    # create beautiful-soup object 
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,'html5lib') 

    # find all links on web-page 
    links = soup.findAll('a') 

    # filter the link sending with .JPG
    img_links = [archive_url + link['href'] for link in links if link['href'].endswith('JPG')] 

    return img_links 


def download_img_series(img_links): 

    for link in img_links: 

        '''iterate through all links in video_links 
        and download them one by one'''

        # obtain filename by splitting url and getting 
        # last string 
        file_name = link.split('/')[-1] 

        print ("Downloading file:%s"%file_name )

        # create response object 
        r = requests.get(link, stream = True) 

        # download started 
        with open(file_name, 'wb') as f: 
            for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size = 1024*1024): 
                if chunk: 
                    f.write(chunk) 

        print( "%s downloaded!\n"%file_name )

    print( "All Images downloaded!")
```

after download i want to delete the image file there. [image]

Answer (score 0):

Get the path in images

```
import os
if os.path.isfile(image_path):
   os.remove(image_path)
```

Comment: i'm getting this image from url i can't use os.

Comment: have you store the images in your localdisk?

Comment: i saved the image into my localdisk and after that i want to delete this image from where i got(means url). you can see the picture.

Comment: what type of URL this? like firebase or any storage

Comment: it's a url from a wifi camera. with the help of this url i fetch the image. but delete part i dont known in that url.

Comment: u can't delete the data from another website.